# python PIL install on shared hosting

Tags: python, compilation, python-imaging-library

I'm going to deploy a django app on a shared hosting provider. I installed my own python in my home, it works fine. My promblem comes with the installation of PIL, i have no support for JPEG after the compile process.

I know that the compiler dont find "libjpeg", so i tried to install it at my home, i download the tar.gz and compile it with

```
./configure -prefix=$HOME/lib
 make
 make install
```

after i put the path in my.bashrc file.

After all i re-compile PIL and still no have the jpeg support.

It is possible to have the libs installed in a shared hosted enviroment? How would I do this?

Comment: why do you think you have to compile anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the machine actually have libjpeg available on it?

Look for /usr/lib/libjpeg.so, and /usr/include/jpeglib.h; they may possibly be in a different lib and include directory. If you can't find them you'll have to also download and compile libjpeg into your home (typically prefix ~/.local).

Then you'll need to add the ‘lib’ path to the ‘library_dirs’ variable and the ‘include’ to ‘include_dirs’ in PIL's setup.py (eg. just under “# add standard directories”), to get it to notice the availability of libjpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Pillow v8 works well on shared hosting cpanel by this current time, python 3.7 pillow==8.0.0

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31302783)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure where your problem comes from,

you can use PIL without compiling anything! just drop the folder in a place that's in PYTHONPATH, and you're all set.

Comment: err? PIL is not going to be much use without the _imaging backend module (libImaging). This is written in C and must be compiled, unless you happen to have downloaded a precompiled binary like the Windows builds.